# Problema con variables numéricas

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario donde hay que escribir la edad del padre y la del hijo.

Por ejemplo, si al padre le pongo 4 y al hijo 22 indica que es correcto; si lo escribo al revés, ocurre lo mismo, siendo incorrecto lo primero.

¿Qué está mal en la función JS?

```
Edad padre<br>
<input type="text" name="padre" id="padre" autocomplete="off">
<br>Edad hijo<br>
<input type="text" name="hijo" id="hijo" autocomplete="off" onchange="edad()" >


<script>
    var padre = document.getElementById("padre").value;
    var hijo = document.getElementById("hijo").value;

    function edad() {

        if (hijo > padre) {
            alert("El hijo no puede tener más años que el padre");
            hijo.value = '';
        } else {
            alert("Las edades son coherentes");            
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes obtener los valor justo cuando se invoca la `funcion edad();` y no antes, en tu codigo actual los datos que obtienes es 0 y 0 con los 2 inputs

```js
function edad() {
  var padre = document.getElementById("padre").value;
  var hijo = document.getElementById("hijo").value;

  if (Number(hijo) > Number(padre)) {
    alert("El hijo no puede tener más años que el padre");
    hijo.value = '';
  } else {
    alert("Las edades son coherentes");
  }

}
```

```html
Edad padre<br>
<input type="text" name="padre" id="padre" autocomplete="off">
<br>Edad hijo<br>
<input type="text" name="hijo" id="hijo" autocomplete="off" onchange="edad()">
```

Answer (score 1):

El `input` `hijo` es un array. Si sólo va a haber un hijo, sacale los corchetes al nombre.

Cambiá `name="hijo[]"` por `name="hijo"`.

**EDIT:**

Estás asignando los valores a las variables por fuera de la función, con lo cual están siempre vacias. Y por otro lado, tenés que transformar los valores en números, porque por defecto son texto.

```
var padre = document.getElementById("padre");
var hijo = document.getElementById("hijo");

function edad() {
    if (parseInt(hijo.value) > parseInt(padre.value)) {
        alert("El hijo no puede tener más años que el padre");
        hijo.value = '';
    } else {
        alert("Las edades son coherentes");
    }
}
```

Comment: He quitado los corchetes y sigue el mismo error. Algo más debo de estar haciendo mal.

Comment: @PacoS probá lo que puse en la edición.